# Is there a way to optimize the batch update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Need to update a table with 100 million records.
Is there a way to optimize this query?

```
DECLARE @rows INT = 1;

WHILE @rows > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(2000) T1
    SET T1.SomeUuid = T2.SomeUuid
    FROM dbo.Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.SomeId = T2.SomeId
                         AND T1.AnotherId = T2.AnotherId
                         AND T1.SomeField = T2.SomeField
    WHERE T1.SomeUuid IS NULL

    SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Tables must use the triple key to join.

Comment: You could try larger batches, like 10000 or 50000.

Comment: Why do you need a loop for this ?

Comment: It is often faster to reconstruct the table by creating a *new* table with the modified values -- and then do a bulk insert all the rows.

Comment: You could add a filtered index with where condition - Index Table1 ON SomeId WHERE SomeUuid = null etc. Make sure that Table2 has an index on SomeId,AnotherID and SomeField

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach and see if it works for you.
The idea is that we prepare the ids ahead and avoid that join and other predicates while just reading the data.
By doing so we narrow the update command to be as simple as possible and improving concurrency.
Any approach you take just remember not to update over few thousands of rows at a time in order to prevent lock escalation.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#data (SomeUuid bigint, AnotherId bigint);
CREATE TABLE dbo.#data_for_iteration (SomeUuid bigint, AnotherId bigint);

-- Get the Ids (Pk or Unique )
INSERT dbo.#data(SomeUuid, AnotherId)
SELECT SomeUuid, AnotherId
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.SomeId = T2.SomeId
                        AND T1.AnotherId = T2.AnotherId
                        AND T1.SomeField = T2.SomeField
WHERE T1.SomeUuid IS NULL;


WHILE 1=1
BEGIN;
    DELETE TOP (2000) #data OUTPUT Deleted .SomeUuid INTO #data_for_iteration ( SomeUuid );
        -- Exite here when done
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN; PRINT  'No more data to process. Terminating'; BREAK; END;

    UPDATE T1
        SET T1.SomeUuid = T2.SomeUuid
    FROM dbo.Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN #data_for_iteration T2 ON T1.SomeId = T2.SomeId             
    
    TRUNCATE TABLE #data_for_iteration;           
END;
```